# anyone knows a way for devise disable the /users routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

Is it possible to disable the /users routing?
I don't want anyone to access /users

Tried several ways like:

```
  resources :users, :skip => [:users] do
    resources :profiles
    resources :account
  end
```

The Users model is my devised one for storing the users login details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you don't want `/users/` but the others routes `/users/:id/`, `/users/:id/profiles`, etc to still be here ? If I'm right, then you don't want the `index` action. So you do `resources :users, :except => [:index] do ...`